# .gca() and .gcf() functions not working when matplotlib embed in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to embed a graph into a tkinter application I am working on. I was able to embed the graph, however, when I try to rotate the x_axis labels (dates) and use the mdates interval, it has no affect on the graph. However, when I load up the graph in its own matplotlib environment, it works fine.

I figure it has to do something with integrating the figure function with the the .gca() and .gcf() functions, as I don't have to deal with Figure() when I have a standalone matplotlib window. I tried doing:

```
fig.plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
fig.plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=7))
fig.plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=30)
```

However, I got AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'plt'
I then tried removing the .plt and leaving only the .fig, however I also got:
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'gcf'

My following code for what I am trying to do is down below:

```py
    def matplot(self,parent):
        company = yf.Ticker('aapl')

        stock_historical = yf.download('aapl', start='2021-08-13', end='2021-10-15', interval='1d')

        get_y = stock_historical
        opening_days = get_y['Open']
        y_axiz = opening_days.values.tolist()
        y_axis = []

        for day in opening_days:
            y_axis.append(round(day, 2))

        stock_historical.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
        data = []

        for i in stock_historical['Date']:
            data.append(i)

        x_axis = []

        for date in data:
            parsed_data = date.to_pydatetime()
            convert_date = str(parsed_data.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
            x_axis.append(convert_date)

        #print(x_axis)
        x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y/%m/%d').date() for d in x_axis]

        # tkinter frame slave of root

        fig = Figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100)

        new_frame = Frame(self.detailed_frame,width=150,height=150)
        new_frame.pack()

        test_label = Label(new_frame,text='hello',font='Arial 16 bold')
        test_label.pack()

        # x_axis shenanigans not wanting to work


        plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
        plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=7))
        plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate(rotation=30)

        fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y_axis)

        # embed into tkinter


        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = new_frame)
        canvas.draw()
        get_widz = canvas.get_tk_widget()
        get_widz.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self.detailed_frame)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

Any help would be appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think of pyplot as Matplotlib's GUI app.  If you embed Matplotlib in your own GUI app, the "pyplot" app does not know about the emended Matplotlib, and hence `plt.gca` etc do not work, because the pyplot app is not keeping track of the figure and axes.  In the above, instead of calling `plt.gca()` call `ax = fig.subplots()` and then `ax.xaxis.set...`

Comment: I tried this already:
`
`fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.plot(x, y_axis)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))`

however, it yielded the same results, no effect.

Comment: Don't use `plt`.

Comment: When I remove the plt from figure() (tried Figure() aswell) I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'XAxis' object has no attribute 'set_major_frmatter'`

Comment: Forget that previous message, was a typo, however, it still does not yield any results when I remove plt

Comment: plz help @jodykymak